# Error when using/importing Libraries in Java Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, import, slf4j

I am trying to use the SLF4J library in my Gradle project. I have done the steps to import External JARs by Eclipse IDE. But I cannot import them to my class.

I have tried:

- To use 'requires' on module-info.java and use 'import' in my class. The error shows "org.slf4j cannot be resolved to a module" in the module-info.java and "The type org.slf4j.Logger is not accessible" for the import in the class file.
- To use the method Class.forName in my class, if I run the program it shows "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer. java.lang.module.FindException: Module trial_1201 not found"
- To use the SLF4J migrator and use a manifest file to run the migrator, but I'm stuck on Error: Could not find or load main class myclass_name. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myclass_name"

SLF4J Libraries in my project that have been imported are:
slf4j-api-2.0.6.jar, slf4j-simple-2.0.6.jar

My .classpath file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-19">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="mypath/snowflake-jdbc-3.9.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="mypath/slf4j-migrator-2.0.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="mypath/slf4j-simple-2.0.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="mypath/slf4j-api-2.0.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="mypath/javax.mail-1.6.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: *What* did you specify with `requires` in the `module-info.java`?

Comment: @nitind  `requires org.slf4j.simple; requires org.slf4j;` . FYI, for the class, I specified the imports as `import org.slf4j.Logger; import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;`

Comment: The external JARs have to be on the _Modulepath_, not on the _Classpath_, in order to be used as modules. In _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Libraries_ move the JARs from the  _Classpath_ to the _Modulepath_. By the way, the `.classpath` file looks like from a plain Java project, not from a Gradle project.

Comment: @howlger sflr, your comment helped me a lot, I was new at gradle so I'm a bit rusty, thanks!